# Prove that $A \times 2A$ is isomorphic to $ B \times 3B$ by using bijection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are sets of real numbers and $A \cong B$ (isomorphic). Let $2A = \{2a|a \in A\}$ and $3B = \{3b|b \in B\}$.
Prove that $A \times 2A \cong B \times 3B$ by finding a bijective function between the sets.

So prove that $A \times 2A$ is a bijective to $B \times 3B$. I am stuck on how to the bijection is injective and surjective. I don't know how to use the given information about the cardinality between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Piquito: Careful -- $A\times 2A$ may well have elements not of the form $(a,2a)$.

Comment: @Hardmath: I understand. Thank you. (I like your nickname).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First, "A x 2A is a bijection" and "B x 3B is a bijection" does not make **any** sense here, these things are sets and not functions. Be sure to know the difference before going on. Now, if $f:A \to B$ is a bijection between $A$ and $B$, define $\varphi: A \times 2A \to B \times 3B$ by $$\varphi(a, 2a') = (f(a), 3f(a')).$$Check that $\varphi$ is bijective using that $f$ is, *by hypothesis*.  Good luck!

Comment: Well technically functions are sets, but the mentioned sets aren't functions so I agree that it sounds like the OP hasn't understood things.

Comment: Yes. I figured that talking about that in the answer would only cause more confusion.